# Changing virtual directories in IIS 7

Tags: c#

I just got a new pc running Windows 7. My old box had XP. I copied all of my files to a newtwork directory, then copied them down to the new pc.

I have an application built in Visual Studio 2003 that I'm trying to do maintenance on. When I try to open it I get the following error message:

Unable to open Web project 'EDIWebFormsUI_1'. The file path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\EDIWebFormsUI_1' does not correspond to the URL 'http://Localhost:/EDIWebFormsUI_1'. The two need to map to the same server location.

I found an article on Microsoft TechNet telling how to change the mapping of a virtual directory at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754640(WS.10).aspx.

However, it says "5. In the Actions panel, click Basic Settings."

I don't have a Basic Settings option in my Actions panel.

I also tried appcmd from the command line, but I get the message "appcmd is not recognized as an internal or external command."

Do you know of another way to change the virtual directory mapping for my application?

Answer (score 0):

VS2003 is a bit old, but there should be a plaintext file somewhere in the project directory that points to the virtual directory location hosting the web project.

Answer (score 0):

To use Appcmd, you may need to change your directory before you try to run the command.  At the command prompt, type **cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv** then run your command.  That should solve the issue.